# Paypal IPN suddenly not responding

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have a site that offers services to paid members. 
When a member subscribes, he goes to Paypal, pays the subscription and then Paypal calls my ipn script which takes care of updating the database and sending a message to the member.
Everything is working fine, but some time ago, I started receiving some messages from Paypal:

"Please check your server that handles PayPal Instant Payment Notifications (IPN).
 IPNs sent to the following URL(s) are failing:

```
http://domain.com/ipnhandler.php
```

If you do not recognize this URL, you may be using a service provider that is
 using IPN on your behalf. Please contact your service provider with the above
 information. If this problem continues, IPNs may be disabled for your account."

I found it strange, because at the same time, people went on subscribing, and the database was updated everytime. So I found strange to receive a message from Paypal saying that the URL was failing... How could it be failing, while the script was working fine?!

Then, one day, the database stopped from being updated. It started in early december, and since then, people pay their subscription but nothing happens. I had a look at the ipn history in my Paypal account, and I can see that Paypal called the script once (only once) for each payment, but the script returned nothing (http response is empptty). And on my side, I had a look at my log file, and there's nothing in it.

In my ipn script, the first thing I do is logging the call in the log file. But it's desperatingly empty since december...

Is there anyone who could help me with this issue? It's very upsetting because I have to register eveything manually... And everything was working fine, so I don't understand why it's not wirking anymre as I didn't change anything in the script neither in Paypal setup.

Please, I really need your help!!!

Thanks

Comment: Maybe your server has a firewall or is there something blocking the incoming requests to that URL?  What about checking out the logs for apache or nginx?

Comment: any idea where I can get these logs? I had a look in my control panel and only found logs for today: and today, a payment was made, and I have nothing in the logs...

Comment: If you are the sys admin go to /var/log if you are not ask your sys admin for those logs

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Does Microsoft Azure have a firewall? My web app isn't receiving the IPN(s), and I think this may be the issue. Any thoughts? Thanks :)

Comment: @Momoro They have security groups, maybe check over there :)

Comment: @VictorCastilloTorres Hmm.. Security Groups? Not sure I've ever heard of them :) Learn something new everyday, huh?

Answer (score 0):

The IPN script will need to load completely in order to return a 200 OK response from your server back to PayPal.  What tends to happen is you could have an error happening near the end of the script after everything else has run, so while it seems like the script completed because you see emails/database updates, etc, it actually did not complete successfully.

Any time I have something going wrong with my IPN stuff I follow the steps in this [guide on testing PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and I'm able to track down the problem.  I would recommend you follow those steps to find your problem.

Comment: I already tested my script in sandbox, and also it has been working fine for weeks. Then suddenly it started not to work, but I didn't change anything in the script.

Comment: Follow the steps in the guide.  You'll find the problem, and then it will make perfect sense.  :)

Comment: I tried to, and here's what I got: I used Paypal simulator and it returned "We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 404: Not Found". This is very strange because when I type the ipn url in my browser, not only it doesn't return a 404 error page, but I can see that it's running ok in my script log file. So I typed the url in my browser, and I saw it in the log file (log file said IPN is invalid, which is normal). Then I tried to make a payment on my site, and nothing happened in the log file (and when I checked paypal ipn history, I can see that Paypal tried to call the script).

Comment: Did you build a local test form and POST it to your IPN URL like Step 1 of that guide says?  You mention using the Simulator which is Step 2 (after the first step is working as expected).  Loading the script in a browser without POSTing data to it isn't a good test because there is no data to process, which is probably where the failure is happening.

Comment: I did as you said and build the test form. But as it's mentioned in the guide, the data is not coming from Paypal's server. So the result can't be "VERIFIED". I'm not sure what to do then... One of the response is: HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request  Is it normal? I'm not sure of what I should change in my ipn script, because with this test, nothing can happen, as one of the things I check is if I have VERIFIED as the response. So what should I do now?

Comment: I made another test: I used Paypal sandbox and the script was executed from beginning until the end (I can see that in the script log file). But when I switch to paypal live environment, nothing seems to be happening: the script log file remains the same. It's pretty strange, don't you think? If the script is working fine in sandbox, why wouldn't it work in live environment ?! I really feel lost, I don't understand what's going on...

Comment: Are you sure you have IPN configured in the live account?

Comment: I know what happened: the IPN script was working fine, but it was returning a 404 error to Paypal, so after a while, Paypal automatically disabled the ipn: that's why it was not working anymore. So I reactivated the IPN in Paypal and it started working again, but my ipn script still returns a 404 error. So Paypal is going to deactivate the ipn sooner or later.

Comment: That's why I need to fix this problem as soon as possible. I had a look and I know what is the line causing the 404 error. You see, I'm using this inside a plugin that I wrote. So in my IPN script, I had to add require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php'); and this line is causing the 404 error. If I don't use this line, then my script can't be executed, because I use a lot of functions that make calls to $wp object for example. And if I have the line, the script works ok, but returns 404 to Paypal...

Comment: I really don't know what to do, and also I don't understand why it's returning this 404 error code... Any idea?

Comment: 404 means not found, as if the URL simply isn't loading anything correctly.  Are you sure you have the URL setup correctly in the PayPal IPN settings?  What is your IPN URL?

Comment: yes, I know what 404 means, that's why I was very surprised to see this 404 error page, because my script was doing the things it was supposed to do, so... I wasn't understanding how it could return a 404 code to paypal! I can give you my paypal url but not on this page. Would you mind giving me your email address?

Comment: About the ipn, as I said, I used the paypal ipn simulator: when I type my actuel ipn script, it says "We could not send an IPN due to an HTTP error: 404: Not Found" (but the script is executed and does what it's supposed to do). Then I took the same script, removed the line require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php'); and in this case, paypal ipn simulator says "IPN sent successfully", but the script returns errors in my log file (fatal error so nothing happens).

Comment: I can't tell you anything about to troubleshoot that I haven't already told you.  I've run into similar issues with people many times and following those procedures I provided fixes it every single time.  If you need more help you could [contact me directly](https://www.angelleye.com/contact-us/) and I could fix it for you, but I'd have to bill for that of course.